# Preg_replace: append absolute path to url but exclude data url

Tags: php, css, regex, preg-replace

In PHP, I use this pattern to append absolute paths to relative URLs in my CSS file:

```
$sCssR = preg_replace('#url\((?!\s*[\'"]?(?:https?:)?//)\s*([\'"])?#', "url($1{$sRel}/", $sCss);
```

The pattern is working well, but **data URLs** like SVG images are effected too.

Example:

```
<? ob_start(); ?>
.url { background:url("//www.test.com/img.png"; }
.url { background:url("http://www.test.com/img.png"; }
.url { background:url("../img/test.png"; }
.url { background:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><circle/></svg>"); }
<?
    $sCss = ob_get_clean();
    $sRel = '//www.test.com/folder';
    $sCssR = preg_replace('#url\((?!\s*[\'"]?(?:https?:)?//)\s*([\'"])?#', "url($1{$sRel}/", $sCss);
    print $sCssR;
?>
```

Output will be:

```
.url { background:url("//www.test.com/img.png"; }
.url { background:url("http://www.test.com/img.png"; }
.url { background:url("//www.test.com/folder/../img/test.png"; }
.url { background:url("//www.test.com/folder/data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><circle/></svg>"); }
```

Everything is fine, except **the last line, which should not be touched** and should look like this:

```
.url { background:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><circle/></svg>"); }
```

Can anyone help me to adjust the preg_replace pattern so 'data:' URLs won't be touched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a trailing `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` component to the end of your pattern:

`~url\((?!\s*[\'"]?(?:https?:)?//)\s*([\'"])?(?:data:(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|)~`

([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dj2X2D/1))

This will effectively "disqualify" urls as you expect.

Comment: Nice, thx! Btw. do you know the difference between using '#url...#' and '~url...~' in the pattern? Both is working,

Comment: There is no difference in this case.  Because you aren't using `#` or `~` inside the pattern itself.  Choosing the best pattern delimiter comes down to selecting a valid delimiter that will not be used in your pattern.  (`~` just happens to be my 1st preference after `/`)  If you choose a pattern delimiter that also occurs inside the pattern itself, then it must be escaped -- this impacts pattern brevity and readability, so I avoid escaping whenever possible.